# Why doesn't Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo appear in the Add References dialog

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have used Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll and Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll in a number of VS2008 projects but they don't appear in the VS2010 Add Reference dialog. Why did they disappear and how can I add them to my VS2010 project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure when I've used those I've always added by browsing to the DLLs themselves (but we're restricted to 2005 at work).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, those assemblies are installed if and when you install the SQL Server client-side tools. They should be visible in the .NET tab of your Add Reference dialog, for sure (if you installed those SQL Server client side tools).

You can also download those libraries separately directly from Microsoft and re-install them. That sometimes helps to "get them back" :-)

Go here: [SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=228de03f-3b5a-428a-923f-58a033d316e1&displaylang=en) and find the `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects` about half way down on the page and download the package you need and install that.

Comment: The assemblies are installed on my system (they appear in VS2008's Add Reference dialog but not in VS2010's.) I tried reinstalling from your link (thanks) but got a message that newer version were already installed.
I can add the reference by browsing to the DLLs as Cade Roux suggests but I'm curious about why they don't appear in VS2010.

Comment: I had the same problem - everything is installed and works perfectly under Vs 2008 while on VS 2010 those assemblies do not appear.

Comment: Same here. VS2010 doesn't list them. If you need to know which DLLs to setup, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162129%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx